# Lotus Notes: Add script to right click menu

Tags: lotus, agent

I have an existing script/agent for Lotus Notes that does something to messages in my mail (removes attachments). The script shows up in the 'Actions' menu.

I would like to add the same script to the right-click menu. How do I do that ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to create an Action in the ($Inbox)- folder. The code of the action is:

```
@Command([RunAgent]; "YourAgent" )
```

In the Action- Properties you can enable the option "Include in right mouse button menu" and give a name to the action.
if you want to use this action in the "All Documents" - View and the "Sent"- View as well it is best practice to create it as a "shared" - Action, then you can reuse it wherever you need it (within your mail database)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there's no way to do.

Why do you want to do that with the right click? Maybe, we can find another solution.